# LinkedIn Ads API - AdAnalyticsV2 - Pagination not working

Tags: pagination, linkedin-api

I wanted to get the first 2 items from the [AdAnalyticsV2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/ads-reporting#ad-analytics) endpoint. As explained [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/paging) you should be able to do this for any service by adding a `count` parameter to the query, but adding e.g. `count=2` to the query doesn't seem to do anything. I still get the same amount items back as usual whenever I add it. Also, changing the `start`, so it just gets the next 10 items, results in the following error: `StatusCodeError: 400 - {"serviceErrorCode":2,"message":"Setting a paging start value is not permitted","status":400}`

Is pagination not available for the AdAnalyticsV2 endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a weird bug with pagination where if there are exactly 10 results and you didn't specify a count it was giving me that message. I set the count to 5000 and have had no problems.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks, Greg!

Comment: @Greg, I have tried setting the count to 5000 and removing the start parameter but no matter what I specify as the count parameter I always get 10 records on the response. 

Request URL is as follows: 
"href=/v2/adAnalyticsV2?accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A2560807&count=5000&dateRange.end.day=20&dateRange.end.month=7&dateRange.end.year=2018&dateRange.start.day=20&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2017&pivot=CAMPAIGN&q=analytics&timeGranularity=MONTHLY"

Any idea?

Thank you!